# Cannot find module strapi npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, strapi

when i run the command npx create-strapi-app@latest  my-project i find this error Cannot find module 'fs-extra' what should i do?

[image]

[image]

I installed the fs-extra module but it does not work, then I typed these two commands npm install -g npm-reinstall, npm install -g npm@latest it still does not work, if you can offer me a solution